# read message value from string.xml file in android

Tags: android

i have string like `@string/screen_enable_auto_mode`. I know that i can use:

```
String mess = getResources().getString(R.string.screen_enable_auto_mode);
```

and i will get a message.

But i have whole string as `@string/screen_enable_auto_mode`. How can i parse it to

```
String mess = getResources().getString(R.string.screen_enable_auto_mode);
```

that i will get a message from xml?

Comment: Please read again your question and edit it. You say: `I have a string and know how to solve the problem for it, but how do I solve it for a string?`. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: What? i know how to use value with R.string.X but i have whole string with @....

Comment: Question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Resources.getIdentifier` for this.

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(
    "screen_enable_auto_mode", "string", "com.package.app");
String mess = getResources().getString(resId);
```

Replace "com.package.app" with the actual package of your app, of course.